# How to plot bars with different height and different width in Matlab with y-axis in logarithmic scale

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If I use following file in Matlab, how I can make the y-axis a logarithmic scale? I tried different ways but it did not work.

```
x = [0.5 0.6 0.9 1 1.2]; % start of bar
    y = zeros(length(x),1);
    dx = diff([x 1.8]); % width of bar
    dy = [1 3 2 .5 .1];
    figure, hold on
    for ii=1:length(x)
        rectangle('position',[x(ii) y(ii) dx(ii) dy(ii)])
    end
    axis([0.5 2 0 4.1])
    ylabel('Prob density')
    xlabel('Time')
```

Comment: Is this for gnuplot? Looks like it but I'm not positive and want to make sure I edited your tags right (this has nothing to do with Windows or Linux).

Comment: Yes, it seems it is my mistake, it is a matlab program

Comment: No I mean y axis.when I put set(gca,'YScale','log'); my plot is rotating somehow and it is getting  weird:( How I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the semilogy function. See the documentation here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html

Comment: No I mean y axis.when I put set(gca,'YScale','log'); my plot is rotating:( How I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the `'YScale'` property after creating your figure or after you're done plotting, e.g.:

```
...
set(gca,'YScale','log');
```

This will also change your y-axis labels and make this particular plot look rather weird. You can fix this by applying an exponential to the y-position in your call to `rectangle`:

```
...
rectangle('position',[x(ii) exp(y(ii)) dx(ii) dy(ii)]);
```

Of course it would be more efficient to do this outside of the `for` loop. It might also be better to try to use `bar` instead.

Note that such a plot will never make complete sense because your bars start at zero (`y`) and `log10(0)` is `-Inf`. Therefore the log scale plot begins at `10^0 = exp(0) = 1` instead.

Comment: How I can do it with bar plot and with controlling height and width? Also considering y axis in log scale, I will plot it not from zero in order not to have problem with log

Comment: @user3271929: `bar` has options for all of those. `bar([0 1],[2 3],1,'w')` creates two white bars at `x=[0 1];` with heights `y=[2 3];` and width `w=1` (your widths will need to be scalar for a given call of `bar`). `bar` centers it's bars at the specified x-values so you may want apply an offset of `w/2` to shift them. Play with it if you want, but I think more is really a separate question from the one you've asked.

Comment: But I need to have it with different width. yes you are right, my fried said you can make your plot with bar . But I think for my case I have to work with rectangle